# Getting syntax error on sql code and cant work out why

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

Been playing around trying to find the syntax error here, sql seems to be spaced out correctly and the variables are reading in from my database and other form as intended.

```
        clsDBConnector dbConnector = new clsDBConnector();
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        dbConnector.Connect();
        string sqlStr1 = "SELECT ItemID" +
            " FROM         TblItem" +
            " WHERE ([Item Name]= " + ItemName + ")";
        dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr1);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string ItemID = dr[0].ToString();
            string sqlStr2 = "SELECT   TOP 1 OrderItemID" +
            " FROM         TblOrderItem" +
            " WHERE(OrderID =" + orderID + ") AND(ItemID =" + ItemID +")";
            dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr2);
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string OrderItemID = dr[0].ToString();
                string sqlStr3 = "DELETE FROM TblOrderItem" +
                    " WHERE    (OrderItemID =" + OrderItemID + ")";
                dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr3);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There should be an exception thrown. Do you read this excpetion message?

Comment: `[Item Name]` suggests its a `(n)(var)char` column, which means the value should be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Aside from whatever exception you're getting, I would *very strongly* advise you to change how you're handling the SQL in general. Use parameterized SQL to: 1) avoid SQL Injection Attacks; 2) Avoid conversion issues; 3) Make the code clearer to read.

Comment: Other than suggesting that you parameterise your queries - have you tried escaping your variables with ' so WHERE([Item Name] = '" + ItemName + "'.

Comment: Show us the final SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you're executing two nested queries on the same connection, but : that usually isn't supported (unless you have "MARS" enabled, which is usually a bad idea). You *should* be seeing an exception about there already being an open data reader on the connection. You need to finish the first reader before you start worrying about additional data. You *could* do that by buffering the data, but frankly I suspect you could also re-work the query to either be one query with a join, or two queries in the same SQL - this would also be more efficient (it avoids "N+1").

The other **major** problem is that you're concatenating data to create SQL, which is invariably a bad idea. At worst it is a SQL injection hole, and at best it saturates your query plan cache. So: please please use parameters instead of concatenation. Parameters also avoid issues of things like escaping, wrapping strings with quotes, and i18n/l10n issues around how to format integers, dates, etc.